# I have one value with an array , and I wanna make a new array, by subtracting a value for each item using php? for example

Tags: php

I have one value with an array , and I wanna make a new array, by subtracting a value for each item using php?  the required example is described here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/37c26.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that image, you can do that very simply. Though I have the feeling you're supposed to figure this out for yourself...

```
$array = array(10, 15, 20);
$newArray = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $newArray[$i] = array[$i] - (10 - 5 * $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$yourfirstarray = array(10,20,30);
$placeholderarray = array();
function Subtract($index,$value){
    $var = $GLOBALS['yourfirstarray'];
    $var2 = $GLOBALS['placeholderarray'];
    $new = $var[$index] - $value;
array_push($var2, $new);
print_r($var2);
}

echo Subtract(0,2);
```

This worked for me, `Index` in this case is the index of the value you wish to change in your array, `echo` of the function prints the return value, in this case, the whole new array